# Gradle Maven Publish - Task 'PGP' not found

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I am trying to use Gradle's Maven Publish plugin to upload to Maven Central. I have gone through the steps of creating a project with Sonatype and was approved. I followed Gradle's Tutorial. After following it I get the following error when running my Continuous Integration action I have made on GitHub.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
132

133
* What went wrong:
134
Task 'PGP' not found in root project 'Display-API'.
135

136
* Try:
137
> Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks.
138
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
139
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Full Error Here: https://github.com/Driftverse/display-api/runs/5444179201?check_suite_focus=true

After further research online I can't seem to figure out what plugin or task is calling the task "PGP".

After running ./gradlew tasks this task is no where to be found. I am still new to using Gradle (I am about 3 days into it). Below I have linked my build.gradle file. What am I doing wrong here and or I am I making all of this way too hard?

- Gradle Version: 7.3
- Language: Java version 17
- Command Used to Build: ./gradlew build publish
- build.gradle: https://github.com/Driftverse/display-api/blob/master/build.gradle
- Following Tutorial: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify some secrets in your CI config:

```
./gradlew build --stacktrace \
  -Prelease=publish \
  -Pversion=${{ steps.tag_version.outputs.new_tag }} \
  -Pwebsite=${{github.server_url}}/${{github.repository}} \
  -PossrhUsername=${{ secrets.OSSRH_USERNAME }} \
  -PossrhPassword=${{ secrets.OSSRH_PASSWORD }} \
  -PsigningKeyId=${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY_ID }} \
  -PsigningKey=${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY }} \
  -PsigningPassword=${{ secrets.SIGNING_SECRET }}
```

I guess one of the secrets contains space followed by `PGP` i.e. `" PGP"`.